# Cannot read property 'root' of null React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, watchman

I have been facing this issue since yesterday and am unable to resolve. I have gone through all github issues filed for react native and watchman, none helped to resolve the issue.

When I try to start react-native inside my project folder using command:

`react-native start`

Following log is thrown in terminal:

> [4:57:26 PM]  Building Dependency Graph [4:57:27 PM] 
>   Crawling File System [Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot
>
> React packager ready.
>
> Failed to build DependencyGraph: Watchman error: Cannot read property
>   'root' of null. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See
>   https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html. Error:
>   Watchman error: Cannot read property 'root' of null. Make sure
>   watchman is running for this project. See
>   https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
>       at /Users/anum/Desktop/Practice/QuizReact/node_modules/node-haste/lib/crawlers/watchman.js:63:11
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

I have updated both watchman and brew to latest versions. Please can someone point me towards right way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I managed to run the react native app successfully. I first updated **npm** using:

```
sudo npm update
```

I deleted my old project, created a new react native project. Then executed these commands step by step, thanks to the [person commented](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1875#issuecomment-139056829):

```
brew update
brew uninstall watchman
brew install watchman --HEAD
```

This time logs did show that both **brew** and **watchman** got updated. Last time I ran commands, they pointed out that my watchman was already updated. It was most probably because **npm** was old, and `react-native` requirements were not fulfilled. So make sure, you have updated all `react-native` stuff to latest versions.

After updating watchman, I started `react-native` server in my project's directory using:

```
react-native start
```

After that, I was able to build and run the project successfully without any error. Hopefully, this answer helps someone!